# ActionBar Compat not showing app icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm setting an ActionBar in my app with the Compatibility version. For now I've done:

- Import android-support-v7-appcompat and add as library to my project
- Set Aplication theme as: Theme.AppCompat
- Extend Activities to ActionBarActivity

After this, I use a method to set dynamically the subtitle:

```
private final void setStatus(int resId) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setSubtitle(resId);
}

private final void setStatus(CharSequence subTitle) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setSubtitle(subTitle);
}
```

While testing the app, the subtitle doesn't appear. If I add this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

Then the subtitle appears, but the app icon dissapears. What can I do to mantain the app icon while showing the subtitle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display options are bitfields, so you should be able to enable several at the same time (using the OR operator), like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(
    ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

Or, to just add one value without affecting other fields, call the version with bitmask:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(
    ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE,
    ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get to solve the problem:

```
/**Resolves the issue, shows the app icon*/
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled (true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getSupportActionbar instead of actionbar

```
Actionbar actionbar = getSupportActionBar()
actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionbar.setIcon(YOUR ICON);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, all of the above answer looks similar with minor differences, none of it work for me but this combo

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled (true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.rn_logo_icon);
```

Please note, this fix is if you are using `AppCompat` theme